# Setting up sparkleshare but keeping old ssh credentials

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I wanted to try out sparkleshare and looked at the tuorials etc.
I understood everything so far, my problem is that I dont know what is going
to happen with my current ssh access if i add the new key.

I am running the git repo on my own mac mini server.
since i need a passwordless ssh key can i use two diffrent keys on the server at the same time,
so i could either connect with a normal ssh client or the sparkleshare client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another key for Sparkleshare, but according to [Sparkleshare's tutorial](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/wiki/How-to-set-up-your-own-server) it can also use the keys already used for SSH login (stored in ~/.ssh).  So, if your client is already set up for passwordless authentication, you shouldn't have to do anything to make it work with Sparkleshare.

Comment: yes but as of know i am using a password ssh as most of the people do, and i cant have two keys at the same time on the server as far as i know?

Comment: adding another key helped, though i had to make some slight changes to my ssh setup

Answer (score 0):

Just got it to work with Snow Leopard 10.6.7 and 10.6.8. I hope it helps.

http://www.instructables.com/id/SparkleShare-for-OSX-a-Dropbox-alternative/